# Calling PerformClick cancels closing event

Tags: c#, winforms

Something strange is happening in my WinForms app (and with strange things it's normally my fault).

I've got a FormClosing event that will check whether any changes has been made on the form that has not been saved.

If the user confirm to save the changes, I will call the Save button's click event.  However, even if I remove all the logic in the OnClick event, the form stays open, and I have to close it again before it closes.

If I skip the line `buttonSave.PerformClick();` then the form closes properly.

Why will entering the click event, cancel the close?  Any work around?

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  //Check if there changes were made on the form
  //Prompt user to save
  if (confirmSave)
     buttonSave.PerformClick();

}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Everything in here commented out.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call the event, instead of using PerformClick?

Comment: I would suggest you, that you take your save logic out of event method and create a new method that could then be called from multiple methods.

Comment: That's the same thing as I said :P

Comment: It really is strange, but calling buttonSave_Click(sender, e); instead of PerformClick works fine.  You are welcome to upgrade that to an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the event instead of `PerformClick`. 
PerformClick probably executes more code that makes the form stop closing. Like showing that the button is clicked, the sound etc.

So change `PerformClick` to `buttonSave_Click`. So it will just do the save function, without doing anything with the button itself.

Comment: @user1208908 upgraded hehe